# Exchange sequences in limit using asymptotical equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to justify rigorously why, in the computation of
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}$$
one can use the Stirling formula
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{\left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}}=1$$
to substitute $n!$ with $\left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}$. It is kind of intuitively clear, but is there a theorem that states this precisely?

Comment: Please, look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1524615/186012).

Comment: I think I didn't understand the OP because to me it seems very basic... Are you asking for a justification of substituting $n!$ with $\left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}$ provided that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{\left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}}=1$?

Comment: That was exactly my question. Now, given the answers below, in the concrete case it is in fact easy to justify. But I think that this depends on the functions involved, since asymptotic equivalence does not behave well with respect to every function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S(n) = (n/e)^n\sqrt {2\pi n}.$ Then

$$\left ( \frac{n!}{n^n} \right )^{1/n} = \left( \frac{n!}{S(n)}\right )^{1/n}\left (\frac{S(n)}{n^n} \right )^{1/n}.$$

Now $n!/S(n) \to 1,$ so certainly $(n!/S(n))^{1/n} \to 1.$ Thus the desired limit equals the limit of $(S(n)/n^n)^{1/n}.$

Answer (score 1):

This is because one uses (asymptotic) equivalence of function. Remember equivalence is compatible with multiplication and division (but *not* with addition or subtraction), and that a function has limit at infinity $\ell$ if and only if its equivalent to $\ell$ at infinity.

*Stirling's formula* essentially says 
$\; n!\sim_\infty\sqrt{2\pi n}\,\Bigl(\dfrac ne\Bigr)^n$. Thus
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}\sim_\infty \sqrt{2\pi n}\frac 1{e^n}$$
Equivalence is also compatible with log, under the condition  the argument of log doesn't approach $1$. This condition is satisfied here, so
$$\log\biggl(\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}\biggr)=\frac1n \log\Bigl(\frac{n!}{n^n}\Bigr)\sim_\infty\frac1n\Bigl(\frac12\log(2\pi n)-n\Bigr)=\frac{\log(2\pi n)}{2n}-1\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}-1, $$
and finally, the limit of the given expression is $\dfrac1e$.

Comment: $\log x$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence we just need that the argument of $\log$ is **positive** to be able to state $\log\lim=\lim\log$.

Comment: For the limit, yes, but for  compatibility with equivalence,  we need the argument to remain outside a small neighbourhod of $1$. If you read French, you can take a look at this [Wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opérations_sur_les_équivalents) which doesn't exist in English, unfortunately.

Comment: I am not sure I really get your objection. Stirling's formula can be written as $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n!e^n}{n^n\sqrt{2\pi n}} = 1 $$ hence by the continuity of the logarithm $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\log(n!)+n-n\log(n)-\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi n)\right)= 0 $$ as well as $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\log(n!)-\log(n)\right)= -1 $$ and by exponentiating back (the exponential function is continuous, too) we get the wanted limit.

Comment: I agree with your computation, of course. I just meant that knowing properties  of logarithm w.r.t. equivalence makes it a little shorter, but there are (mild) restrictions to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Stirling's formula can be written as $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n!e^n}{n^n\sqrt{2\pi n}} = 1 $$ hence by the continuity of the logarithm over $\mathbb{R}^+$ we get $\log\lim=\lim\log$, i.e. $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\log(n!)+n-n\log(n)-\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi n)\right)= 0 $$ from which it follows that $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\log(n!)-\log(n)\right)= -1 $$ and by exponentiating back (the exponential function is continuous, too) we get the wanted limit:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\frac{1}{e}.$$